# Cant lock screen orientation on iPad iOs

Tags: ios, react-native, ipad, expo, screen-orientation

*NOTE i am aware there are many post about this already. But all are somewhat outdated and not a single one fixes the issue hence i am posting a new one.*

**Issue**

Cant lock a specific screen orientation for ipad.

**Packages**

```
"expo": "~44.0.0",
"expo-screen-orientation": "^4.1.2",
"react": "17.0.1",
"react-dom": "17.0.1",
"react-native": "0.64.3",
(Ands loads of others that arent relevent)
```

**Info**

Trying to lock a screen orientation to landscape.
Here's the catch: on mobile it should be portrait but on tablet - landscape. Mobile works fine (both orientations), but on tablet - cant seem to make it work.

And yes, I did add `"requireFullScreen": true` to `app.json`. and `app.json` does NOT contain `orientation` property (tried with it too tho).

FUN FACT - tried setting `orientation` to landscape on `app.json` and on iPhone it was fine but on iPad - did nothing. I could still rotate the screen just fine.

**Code**

In the top most app (`app.js`) I create a simple method (inside `function App()` ):

```
  const foo = async () => {
    await ScreenOrientation.lockAsync(ScreenOrientation.OrientationLock.LANDSCAPE_LEFT);
  };
```

And i call it: `foo();`

Then the return (that is not relevent). NOTE the app is returned like so `export default registerRootComponent(App);`

If using an iPhone - it works fine. But with iPad - i can rotate the screen (aka its not locked).

Tried many different iPads (emulators) and none seem to work.

As mentioned - there are many reports but none seem to be up to date nor working.

Comment: Same here, ipad device can rotate the screen following the above approaches
https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/5339 - a  user in this thread mentions that it should work normally after building, can you confirm?

Comment: @CheeJiaYuan This has been tried after the issue here was opened. The results are the same aka what the user said can NOT be confirmed

Comment: Ah I see, I will continue working on my end to see how to get it resolved, however, this won't be a high priority issue for me for now

Comment: Understandable. We also switched our focus to more relevant/important stuff. If you figure it out in the future then I would appreciate if you could share your finding with us :) @CheeJiaYuan

Answer (score 0):

From the Expo [docs](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/screen-orientation/):

> Apple added support for split view mode to iPads in iOS 9. This changed how the screen orientation is handled by the system. To put the matter shortly, for the iOS, your iPad is always in the landscape mode unless you open two applications side by side. In order to be able to lock screen orientation using this module you will need to disable support for this feature. For more information about the split view mode, check out the [official Apple documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207582).

Of course this basically tells us nothing.

Comment: hmh... Sounds interesting. Have you yourself, or someone reading this, tried if locking screen orientation works on ios devices with this split screen feature disabled? because it does sound like a probable solution

Comment: I can't seem to locate any official documentation that mentions opting out of the feature. I think maybe it's mandatory now or something.

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same issue and the way I went around it worked for me. Open your react-native project in XCode (by opening the respective `xcworkspace` file). Click on the Files icon on the left, and click on your project. For me, it is something like this: -
[file as seen in xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gXOk.png)

After clicking on that, you should see your project settings. Click on General, and in that page, you should find a tab namely 'Deployment Info'. Under this tab, you should find 'Device Orientation'. Click on the checkbox next to 'Portrait' and your issue should be fixed.

[image with checkboxes in XCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vjoF.png)

Comment: this does not allow the flexibility of having different orientation for different devices. example: phone - portrait, tablet - landscape.
+ these settings will not be effected since its not being build or used by xcode in any way shape or form. the project is build by other processes that only fetch the code from GIT.